# use strtok to separate string and store in struct

Tags: arrays, c, struct, structure, strtok

i guess i should rephrase my question. i have a structure like below:

```
struct profile {
    char name[30];
    int age, phoneNo;
};
```

i have a file with strings that look like this:

```
James Brown,35y,0123456789
Mary Brown,45y,0123987456
```

currently i've written a code to search for a record using the person's name/age/phoneNo, and i'd like to store the records into the struct i have. i'm trying to use `strtok` to separate the data from the comma, but my code is not working.

```
int main()
{
    char search[50];
    char record[50];
    const char s[2] = ",";
    char* token;
    struct profile c;

    FILE* fPtr;
    if (fPtr = fopen("profile.txt", "r"))
    {
        // flag to check whether record found or not
        int foundRecord = 0;
        printf("Enter name to search : ");
        // fgets gets name to search
        fgets(search, 50, stdin);
        //remove the '\n' at the end of string
        search[strcspn(search, "\n")] = 0;

        
        while (fgets(record, 50, fPtr))
        {
            // strstr returns start address of substring in case if present
            if (strstr(record, search))
            {
                token = strtok(record, s); 

                while (strtok != NULL)
                {

                    scanf("%s", c.name);
                    token = strtok(record, s);
                    scanf("%d", c.age);
                    token = strtok(record, s);
                    scanf("%d", c.phoneNo);
                    token = strtok(NULL, s);

                    printf("Your details: ");
                    printf("%s, %d, %d\n", c.name, c.age, c.phoneNo);

                }
                
                foundRecord = 1;
            }
        }
        if (!foundRecord)
            printf("%s cannot be found\n", search);

        fclose(fPtr);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("File cannot be opened\n");
    }
}
```

i've never used `strtok` before and i'm not sure how to store each token into each struct variables. could someone explain to me how i can fix the `strtok` function in my code?

Comment: Read the description of the function strtok. You can find it in the internet.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i've read up about strtok on the internet, but i'm not to how to apply it to structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As advised in comments, you can easily read a comma delimited string using [`strtok`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm). You can use [`atoi`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_atoi.htm)/[`sscanf`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm) to extract integer value from age. I modified your code a little to read from file to assign to struct array:

```c
// Array for storing Profiles
struct profile profiles[2];

FILE* fPtr;
if (fPtr = fopen("profile.txt", "r")) {
    int index = 0;
    while (fgets(record, 50, fPtr) != NULL) {
        // Extract name
        char *pStr = strtok(record, ",");
        if (pStr != NULL) {
            strcpy(profiles[index].name, pStr);
        }
        // Extract Age
        pStr = strtok(NULL, ",");
        if (pStr != NULL) {
            profiles[index].age = atoi(pStr);
        }
        // Extract Phone No
        pStr = strtok(NULL, ",");
        if (pStr != NULL) {
            profiles[index].phoneNo = atoi(pStr);
        }
        index++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("%s %d %d\n", profiles[i].name, profiles[i].age, profiles[i].phoneNo);
    }
     
    fclose(fPtr);
}
```

When I ran this, I was able to see expected output:

```
src : $ cat profile.txt 
James Brown,35y,0123456789
Mary Brown,45y,0123987456
src : $ gcc readfiletostructarr.c 
src : $ ./a.out 
James Brown 35 123456789
Mary Brown 45 123987456
```

Comment: thank you so much! this helped me get an idea of how strtok works with structs and i'm certain i'm able to program mine now. i really appreciate this, have a nice day! :)

Comment: Np, I'm happy that I was able to help :-)